# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

**Error :**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager
>                                                                        at
>   android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setError(TextInputLayout.java:379)

**Build gradle file :**
android {

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.inn.microwave"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
}
```

**Dependencies :**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1' 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the support libraries have to be the same version. Try changing either appcompat-v7 and support-v4 to 23.0.1 or design to 23.1.1